# Return most recently modified folder in cmd?

Tags: cmd

I need a simple command to run in cmd which prints or returns (or anything similar) the most recently modifed folder within a directory. I have very basic knowledge of these commands so simple answers would be best! I have already tried dozens of different solutions and none of them work. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this batch script:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('dir /b /ad-h /t:w /od') DO SET a=%%i
echo Most recently modified subfolder: %a%
pause
```

You can change `t:w`, wich gives you last write date, with `t:c` if you want the last created one.

This works with current directory but if you want to run in another directory you can change it like this:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('dir "c:\testdir" /b /ad-h /t:w /od') DO SET a=%%i
echo Most recently modified subfolder: %a%
pause
```

Note that `/ad-h` gives you only directories but not the hidden ones.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your answer. However, all this does is list every subfolder within the specified folder. Any way I could alter this so that ONLY the most recently modified folder shows?

Comment: `echo Most recent subfolder: %a%` this line shows you the most recently modified folder.